# Probability distribution of a multiplying sample size

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Every gene in a sample has a chance to multiply (IE, make a copy of itself) each time a cycle is performed. If a gene doubles, both new genes will have a change to double in the next cycle. However, if one gene in a sample doubles, it does not mean they all will (IE, if you had $2$ genes, you could end up with $2,3$ or $4$ genes after the cycle).

If $p$ is the probability that the sample will double, and the cycles begin with $1$ gene, what is the probability distribution for each number of total genes after $10$ multiplying cycles.

I think the distribution will between $1$ and $1024$, but the question is not binomial and I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Do you mean "the cycles begin with one gene"?  If not, what does "the cycles begin with one sample" mean?

Comment: @saulspatz, yep, sure did, sorry

Comment: Yours is a simple case of a branching process: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branching_process ...  Using the wikipedia article's notation, in your example $X_{n,i} = 2$ with probability $p$ and $= 1$ with probability $(1-p)$.  However, I don't know if your special case has a better closed form solution.  I can also think of some recurrence, but those would be very tedious to compute.